# Is the phrase "factor is because" a little bit wordy

Tags: word-usage

[An IELTS learning material website](https://ieltssharebox.com/how-to-get-high-score-in-ielts-speaking-band-9.html) gives this response for question "Why did you choose that job"

> To be honest, I make a choice of this job with two main reasons. At first, I am in love with teaching English to children. **Another factor is because** my hometown lacks a lot of English teachers so it is easier for me to get a job here and live closely with my parents.

Is the phrase "another factor is because" a little bit wordy?

Is the following more concise?

> ... **Another factor is the lack** of English teachers in my hometown ...

Comment: The passage is understandable, but poorly written—and borderline ungrammatical in some parts. It's a good example of how *not* to write, rather than how *to* write. That site, based on that writing, is not a place you want to learn English from. (*Another factor* is normal; it's one of the few normal things about the passage. Your version is more concise, but I'd point to it as one of the least needed changes.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. Does "borderline" here refer to some part that quoted paragraph as a response?

Comment: "Another factor is because" IS wordy, yes. But it's also ungrammatical. A noun is needed, not a reason. Your "Another factor is the lack..."  is much better. As Jason Bassford said, the *whole* passage is poorly written and unidiomatic.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian No, that part isn't ungrammatical. (It's used far too often to be considered incorrect in any idiomatic or descriptive sense.) I wasn't referring to that. *I **make** a choice of this job with* ***two main reasons*** doesn't make any sense. And while *at first, I am in love with teaching* can be fine in some contexts, this isn't really one of them. There are several parts of this passage that are wrong or unusual. However, *another factor is because* is not one of them. *Because X* can be treated as a noun phrase even if it's not accepted in *formal* English.

Comment: @Jason Bassford You say *Another factor is because* is "used far too often to be considered incorrect . . ." yet Ngram doesn't find any examples of its use. All the rest I agree with. Sorry if I misrepresented your comment.

Comment: @shiqangpan Yes! *Another factor is the lack of English teachers in my hometown* is MUCH better. ('Shortage' rather than 'lack' perhaps.)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Perhaps not ***factor*** specifically, but look at the Google Ngram for [*another **reason** is because*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+reason+is+because&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canother%20reason%20is%20because%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Canother%20reason%20is%20because%3B%2Cc0z). In the sense being used in the question, I consider *factor* and *reason* to be synonymous—especially because *reason* is used in the first sentence, so two reasons are  being given.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian To fix things more properly, the first sentence should read *I make a choice of this job **because of two factors**. First,  …* And then the other change you suggest: *another **factor** is **that** my hometown …* But I feel that fixing one without fixing the other is worse than leaving *factor* in place as the equivalent of *reason*. Although, even that is still strange. Really, it should be *first* and *second*, dropping *another [whatever] is because* altogether.

Comment: @shiqangpan I would recommend this: "I chose this job for two main reasons. Firstly because I love teaching children English, and secondly because the shortage of English teachers in my hometown means it'll be easier for me to get a job there and live near my parents."